# Ubuntu won't boot up

Tags: asus

During the install (dual boot) there where several messages that went " warning: source id 'different numbers-ex.{ 26108 }' was not found when trying to remove it".
I restarted my computer like it said and I just booted up windows like it normally would have, nothing about it in the bios & the partition is blank when I go into 
computer(right cl)>manager(windows)
. My model number is  X401U.

Comment: I'd take a look at the [UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uefi) tag if I were you.. Sadly there seem to be a lot of unanswered questions there, but I hear it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Ubuntu and Windows on two separate partitions on the same HDD?
Unfamiliar with your error but, they will cause a lot of problems like taking boot priority over eachother, I keep Windows on different HDD's from other OS's.

I don't recommend using any of Windows recovery options if you get an error.
I don't understand, what partition is blank?